# Peforce revert if p4 diff has no changes

Tags: perforce

I want to revert the file based on the perforce diff condition

If there are no changes in perforce diff then i need to perform revert otherwise nothing

the following are perforce commands i am using in my code

For perforce diff

_conn.RunCommand(PerforceCommands.DIFF, "-a", FileDepotLocation);

Based on the above command i need to revert the file

_conn.RunCommand(PerforceCommands.REVERT, "-a", FileDepotLocation);

Right now i have following code

```
   public void RevertIfUnchanged() {
     if (FileMode != FileMode.NotOpened) {
        _conn.RunCommand(PerforceCommands.DIFF, "-du", FileDepotLocation);
        _conn.RunCommand(PerforceCommands.REVERT, "-a", FileDepotLocation);

        FileMode = FileMode.NotOpened;
        CheckIfInSync();
     }
      }
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What precisely is the question? 'revert -a' is indeed the right way to revert a file only if it is unchanged.

Comment: Setting up your client correctly will have this happen anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As Bryan was alluding to, you don't need to do the diff yourself before reverting.  By specifying the `-a` option in your revert command, you're telling Perforce to only revert files that are unchanged.